# RSpec - NoMethodError for methods called on associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I'm trying to test my expense report app. While I'm calculating the tax on an item, I need to do a lookup to see if tax should be applied to an item.

My item_spec.rb:

```
describe Item do
  subject {Item.new(:report_id => 26 ,  :name => 'Gas' ,  :tax_id => 1 ,  :category_id => 15 ,  :sub_category_id => 1 ,  :job_id => 1 , :total => 20 )}
  let(:tax) {Tax.find_by_id(subject.tax_id)}
  let(:sub_category) {SubCategory.find_by_id(subject.sub_category_id)}

  it 'Calculate Taxes and Cost' do
    subject.set_nil_values    
    subject.calculate_tax(:tax, :sub_category)
  end
end
```

This is the error I get:

```
  1) Item Calculate with just Total
     Failure/Error: subject.calculate_tax(:tax, :sub_category)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `rate' for :tax:Symbol
     # ./app/models/item.rb:88:in `calculate_tax'
     # ./spec/models/item_spec.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is the line that it's failing on in my "calculate_tax" method:

```
self.tax_rate = tax.rate
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the function `calculate_tax` passing in `tax` and `sub_category` helpers directly not symbols, like follows:

```
subject.calculate_tax(tax, sub_category)
```

Have a look at the documentation and usage here: [Let and let!](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let)

Comment: Thanks!  1 Question - I was able to "fix" it by instead doing this:  @tax = Tax.find_by_id(subject.tax_id) and passing in '@tax' and '@sub_category' - what is the difference between using Let, and setting an instance variable?

Comment: @fatfrog, there is difference between the two and it's recommended to use `let`.  Please see http://bitfluxx.com/2011/05/23/some-rspec-tips-and-best-practices.html post which describes this very well.